# android-studio project error .zip extract: path too long

Tags: windows, android-studio, path, zip

I just recently tried to extract a .zip file that contains a android-studio project from my usb key. I moved the .zip file on my desktop and then used the 'extract-all' from windows. During the extract, I get this message:

[image]

Now If I would change the name of the class, it would probably give me errors when I build gradle. Is there a way to simply override this error message ? Is this a windows issue or is it an android-studio problem (naming files too long)?

So far, I've tried extracting each file but it didn't work. I've also tried it on other computers and its the same result... Any ideas on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 7zip [link](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), this will likely solve your problem!